# How to change size and color of different cell in same section when we r having multiple section in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I want to change the size and color of the different row (cell) in specified section so can any one give me the suggestion how to manage it..
Actually i m using 4 section on same view and i want to change the cell color and cell size in
section 4 for that i wrote the following code in "heightForRowAtIndexPath" method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section==0)
    {
        return 44;
    }
    else if(indexPath.section==2)
    {
        return 44;

    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (indexPath.row==0) 
        {
            label6.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
            label6.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            return 44;
        }

        else if(indexPath.row==1)
            {
                return 100;
                label6.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0,120,100); 
                label6.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
                label7 .frame=CGRectMake(122, 0,200,100); 
                label7.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];

            }
            else
            {
                label6.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0,120,40); 
                label7 .frame=CGRectMake(122, 0,200,40); 

                return 44;
            }

        }


}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Priyanka.

Comment: what is exactly the problem you are having with this code? it is not clear from your question...

Comment: only the Else part of my code is not working properly.So do u have any suggestion regarding it......Actually,i have already initialized this 2 lables(label6 & label7) in cellForRowAtIndexPath() according to sections and now in the else code i have to just change its size & color.

Comment: the color of what cell or labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now from the above question as far as i understood you want to change the height and cell color for some sections that you are making in your code well try the below code

In order to change the height of a particular cell in your section copy+paste the height for row method of the table view which is a delegate protocol which you have already done in your code here's a view at my code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            if(indexPath.row ==2)
            {
                return 25;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if(indexPath.row ==2)
            {
                return 25;
            }
            break;


    }

    return tableView.rowHeight;   
}
```

and now in the next part what i have done is changed the cell color for some rows i hope the code is self explanatory. Select the cell for row at index path method and add this code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if(indexPath.row ==2)
        {
            //changing cell color
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }

    }
    else if(indexPath.section ==1)
    {
        if(indexPath.row ==2)
        {
            //changing cell color
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.....

Comment: if you are using custom cells then in that case in place of textLabel you may use the labels that you create

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of the cell in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You will need to do that in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You should however pass the custom height in this method. So it would become,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 1:
        return 100;

    case 3:
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            return 100;
        }

    default:
        return 44;
    }
}
```

You can make all your cell customization in

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    ...

    if ( indexPath.section == 3 ) {
        switch ( indexPath.row ) {
        case 0:
            cell.label6.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
            cell.label6.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.label6.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0,120,100); 
            cell.label6.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
            cell.label7.frame=CGRectMake(122, 0,200,100); 
            cell.label7.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
            break;

        default:
            cell.label6.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0,120,40); 
            cell.label7.frame=CGRectMake(122, 0,200,40);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `label6` and `label7` are members of the `cell`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Strangely, the accepted answer seems to have changed.

Comment: still hv some lill problem actually i have already initialized label6 above the switch case like this "label6 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0,120, 44)] ; " and in switch case like this "label6.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);" so according to  "label6 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0,120, 44)] ; " the label ll set. but i want 320 as width not 120 so any solution..